# how to add printer during print using cordova ionic 2 in android/ios

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, printing, cordova-plugins

I want to create an application which would support native print as shown in the picture.

[image: android native print ui]

Does ionic 2/3 support this kind of feature?

I have come across https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer

Although I doubt this support prints outside the application. I have to still print even the document has opened from a different application.

Comment: Is this even possible for Ionic to support adding new printer service in android and ios both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to install the native print plugin and then extend an android PrintService, which will add my printer in the list.

had to add 
PrinterCapabilitiesInfo printerCapabilitiesInfo = new PrinterCapabilitiesInfo.Builder

PrinterInfo printerInfo = new PrinterInfo.Builder

To generate the printer capabilities and add this to

printerInfoList.add(printerInfo)

the following got me the file.

@Override
    protected void onPrintJobQueued(PrintJob printJob) {
        final File file = getFile(printJob);

```
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
    startActivity(intent);

    printJob.cancel();
}
```

Comment: and do not miss to remove then add the platform